# Polygon doesn't appear in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, polygon-creation

I have created a polygon shapefile and the nodes can be seen in edit mode:
[image]

and here is the symbology as I have tried to set it (I wanted no fill and red outline):

[image]

The polygon doesn't appear on the backdrop.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you check if the attribute table has an entry?

Comment: Can you add a new symbol layer and delete the Simple Fill. Change the newly added one to 'Outline:Simple Line. This is just to basically reset any changes you might have made.
Next check in the General tab that you haven't enabled 'Scale dependent Visibility'

Comment: Did as suggested @Freighty but still no joy.  The attribute table is minimalist but does have an entry.

Comment: Maybe an stupid idea... : Is it possible that the polygon you want to display is behind other(s) layers? I guess it may be be behind your green polygons in the screenshot so if the border is not width enough, you can't see it...

Comment: Yes @YoLecomte that had occurred to me, but even after removing the blue and green filled polygons it still isn't there.

Comment: Never got to the bottom of this but problem solved by reloading layer.